# merge common elements of a list of dictionary and store uncommon elements in a new key

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very big dictionary with keys containing a list of items, these are unordered. I would like to group certain elements in a new key. For example

`input= [{'name':'emp1','state':'TX','areacode':'001','mobile':123},{'name':'emp1','state':'TX','areacode':'002','mobile':234},{'name':'emp1','state':'TX','areacode':'003','mobile':345},{'name':'emp2','state':'TX','areacode':None,'mobile':None},]`

for above input i would like to group areacode and mobile in a new key `contactoptions`

```
opdata = [{'name':'emp1','state':'TX','contactoptions':[{'areacode':'001','mobile':123},{'areacode':'002','mobile':234},{'areacode':'003','mobile':345}]},{'name':'emp2','state':'TX','contactoptions':[{'areacode':None,'mobile':None}]}]
```

i am doing this now with a two long iterations. i wanted to achieve the same more efficiently as the number of records are large. open to using existing methods if available in packages like pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regular dictionaries, you can do it in a single pass/loop using the setdefault method and no sorting:

```
data = [{'name':'emp1','state':'TX','areacode':'001','mobile':123},{'name':'emp1','state':'TX','areacode':'002','mobile':234},{'name':'emp1','state':'TX','areacode':'003','mobile':345},{'name':'emp2','state':'TX','areacode':None,'mobile':None}]

merged = dict()
for d in data:
    od = merged.setdefault(d["name"],{k:d[k] for k in ("name","state")})
    od.setdefault("contactoptions",[]).append({k:d[k] for k in ("areacode","mobile")})
merged = list(merged.values())
```

output:

```
print(merged)
# [{'name': 'emp1', 'state': 'TX', 'contactoptions': [{'areacode': '001', 'mobile': 123}, {'areacode': '002', 'mobile': 234}, {'areacode': '003', 'mobile': 345}]}, {'name': 'emp2', 'state': 'TX', 'contactoptions': [{'areacode': None, 'mobile': None}]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
result = (
    df.groupby(['name', 'state'])
      .apply(lambda x: x[['areacode', 'mobile']].to_dict(orient='records'))
      .reset_index(name='contactoptions')
    ).to_dict(orient='records')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you asked, you want to group the input items by 'name' and 'state' together.

My suggestion is, you can make a dictionary which keys will be 'name' plus 'state' such as `'emp1-TX'` and values will be list of 'areacode' and 'mobile' such as `[{'areacode':'001','mobile':123}]`. In this case, the output can be achieved in one iteration.

Output:

```
{'emp1-TX': [{'areacode':'001','mobile':123}, {'areacode':'001','mobile':123}, {'areacode':'003','mobile':345}], 'emp2-TX': [{'areacode':None,'mobile':None}]}
```